# How do I get rid of the white space between my tabs and the table in react.js?

Tags: reactjs

Below is the image of the page: [image]

Below is the image of my code, the issue is something to do with the tabs tag, I don't know how to make the white space change into matching the background color, (the backgroundColor:'#EEEEEE' does not work.

```
<Box sx={{ bgcolor: 'background.paper', width: '25%' }}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={tabValue}
          onChange={handleTabChange}
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          textColor="inherit"
          variant="fullWidth"
          aria-label="full width tabs example"
          TabIndicatorProps={{
            style: {
              backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
              height: '3px',
            },
          }}
        >
          <Tab label="Active" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Inactive" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Applicants" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
    </Box>
```

Comment: Could you recreate this in a sandbox ?

Comment: start by opening dev tools, and finding out which element that area belongs to. Then see which CSS rule(s) is/are responsible for making it show up, and then first start update those rules in the browser until things look right, then just... update your files to use the new rules.